# regex for stripping the first 3 columns of data separated by pipe symbol

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text file with values separated by the pipe symbol `|`

```
data|baloney|198237423984732|cheese|more cheese|98746464
```

I want to remove the first three columns, so for example I am left with

```
cheese|more cheese|98746464
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this regex:

```
^([^|]*\|){3}
```

to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the last three columns for you as per your example.

```
([^|]*\|){2}[^|]*$
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/et9US16DZa).